# Does posting pictures on Facebook mean that I lose rights over them?

Tags: facebook

I am not certain of the status of the pictures I upload to Facebook.

Does posting pictures mean that I lose rights over them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Facebook's own pages:

> **Do I retain the copyright and other legal rights to material I upload to Facebook?**
>
> Yes, you retain the copyright to your content. When you upload your content, you grant us a license to use and display that content. For more information please visit our Statement of Rights and Responsibilities, which contain information about intellectual property, as well as your privileges and responsibilities as a Facebook user.

[Source](http://www.facebook.com/#!/help/?faq=12008)

Additionally you have control over who can view your photos and also which application have access to them.

This is the relevant part from the license you are signing up to:

> For content that is covered by intellectual property rights, like photos and videos ("IP content"), you specifically give us the following permission, subject to your privacy and application settings: you grant us a non-exclusive, transferable, sub-licensable, royalty-free, worldwide license to use any IP content that you post on or in connection with Facebook ("IP License"). This IP License ends when you delete your IP content or your account unless your content has been shared with others, and they have not deleted it.

[Source](http://www.facebook.com/#!/terms.php)

Answer (score 1):

Note the following excerpt above from Facebook's ToS:

> This IP License ends when you delete your IP content or your account
> unless your content has been shared with others, and they have not
> deleted it.

When you delete your photos, FB loses the non-exclusive, royalty-free license to use them. The “unless…” part is tricky, however, because if your friends have shared and not deleted the photos, FB still has the license to use your photos.

Fortunately, FB tells you which users have shared your photos. Might be as “simple” as sending them PMs requesting them to delete your photos. Complications arise, however, if **their** friends then re-shared.

Answer (score 0):

you are agreeing to grant them a “non-exclusive license”. This means that they can sell all or part of your images, and use them however else they wish, in perpetuity, including using elements of your images in virtual realit andd AI business they conduct.

Comment: Your answer is at odds with the accepted answer (which admittedly is 13 years old).  Your answer would be more valuable if you provided information supporting your answer as was done in previous answers.

Answer (score -2):

According to the FB terms of service, in a word yes.  In many words, FB gains all rights to use any and all material uploaded on their servers.

Comment: That doesn't mean you LOSE them. See ChrisF's answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/809/does-posting-pictures-on-facebook-mean-that-i-lose-rights-over-them/813#813